# Laravel 4: get unencrypted cookies

Tags: php, cookies, laravel, laravel-4

I know that, Laravel encrypt cookie before set it, then when retreive it (if changed) will not returned,

but in my case I set Cookie using JavaScript and need to get it from Laravel?

thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

retrieve it using PHP $_COOKIE

```
$_COOKIE["test"]
```